# Django-rest-framework - JWT authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

In my `settings.py` file I have set this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Now, I have created a `ListCreateAPIView`:

```
class ListSubreddits(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Subreddit.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, )

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return SubredditSerializer_detailed
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return SubredditSerializer
```

So, I have sent a **POST** request creating without just `content-type` header and the **POST** request was successful. I haven't provided any **Authentication** or **Authorization** headers. What am I missing here?

Comment: please post all info about REST_FRAMEWORK in settings.py

Answer (score 3):

you must add permission to your view :

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class ListSubreddits(ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Subreddit.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication, )
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return SubredditSerializer_detailed
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return SubredditSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your settings for `REST_FRAMEWORK` in settings.py to the following:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```